# How to implement input handling in libgdx with ananymous inner class in kotlin

Tags: libgdx, kotlin

I want to implement below example from **libgdx** wiki in **Kotlin**

[image]

**Here is my attempt:**

```
Gdx.input.inputProcessor = InputAdapter() {
        override fun touchDown(x: Int, y: Int, pointer: Int, button: Int): Boolean {
            // My code
            return true
        }
    }
```

but I definitely do something wrong

Comment: http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be:

```
Gdx.input.inputProcessor = object : InputAdapter() {
    override fun touchDown(x: Int, y: Int, pointer: Int, button: Int): Boolean {
        // My code
        return true
    }
    override fun touchUp(x: Int, y: Int, pointer: Int, button: Int): Boolean {
        // My code
        return true
    }
}
```